# Flutter BLoC multiple BLoCs same widget

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm relatively new to Flutter and the BLoC pattern, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around everything.

Let's say I have a quiz app where I have a BLoC called `QuestionBloc` which uses a repository to fetch questions from a file.
Event on `QuestionBloc`

- `FetchQuestion`

States on `QuestionBloc`

- `QuestionEmpty`
- `QuestionLoading`
- `QuestionLoaded` which contains a question object
- `QuestionError`

I then have another BLoC called `QuestionValidatorBloc` which is responsible for validating the answers to the question. The answer is entered into a text field and there is a submit button to trigger the validation.
Event on `QuestionValidatorBloc`

- `ValidateQuestion`

States on `QuestionValidatorBloc`

- `ValidateInitial`
- `ValidateInProgress`
- `ValidateSuccess`
- `ValidateError`

This is fairly straight forward. However, now I need to incorporate both `QuestionBloc` and `QuestionValidatorBloc` into the same widget since one of them is responsible for fetching and displaying the question and the other for handling the validation action. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What if you use just one BloC, and 2 or more subjects? You're using the same widget. So its better to have only one BLoC and streams builders as needed

Comment: Split two different job in two bloc is positive imo. I saw a lot of peope told one bloc for one page, but I thought they didn't see more complex use case. In this case, `validation` and `api call` is absolutely different job, I don't know why use one is better adoption.

Comment: What if I need another bloc, inside of this bloc? I'm talking about using 2+ bloc's inside of bloc. I would probably have 2 subscriptions, but how would I nest it? State listener in another state listener is bad approach :/ I'm stuck

Answer (score 5):

I assumed you are using the `flutter_bloc` library. Let the `QuestionBloc` listen to the `QuestionValidatorBloc` using `StreamSubscription`

```
class QuestionBloc extends Bloc<QuestionEvent, QuestionState> {
  QuestionValidatorBloc questionValidatorBloc;
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  MainPageBloc({@required this.questionValidatorBloc}) {
    subscription= questionValidatorBloc.state.listen((state) {
      if (state is ValidateSuccess) {
        dispatch(YourEvent());
      } else if(state is ValidateError{
        dispatch(AnotherEvent());
      }
    });
  }

...
```

Now you just have to pass the `QuestionValidatorBloc` to the `QuestionBloc` constructor.

Comment: What if I need another bloc, inside of this bloc?
I'm talking about using 2+ bloc's inside of bloc. I would probably have 2 subscriptions, but how would I nest it? State listener in another state listener is bad approach :/ I'm stuck

Comment: @fkvestak Have you figured it out?

Comment: @Spectarion no, i'm simply not using bloc anymore, you should try mobx

Comment: @AnisAlibegić since `bloc.state` is a `Stream` you could combine multiple streams together and then listen to a combination of streams as a single `Stream` object. if dart doesn't have anything for that rxdart library definitely has